# Why is adding overflow:hidden causing an element to shrink

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI, and have built a toolbar (a div element), with button groups (span element), each containing buttons, radios etc.

On some of the radio buttons, I have created complex labels to simulate MS Word 2007 style buttons. There is an iframe with a style preview, and a p element with the button name.

E.g.

```
<label ... >
   <iframe ... ></iframe>
   <p>Button Name</p>
</label>
```

Some button names could be very long, so I gave the p class "overflow:hidden". This has corrected the overflow, but the label has shrunk in height slightly in firefox, and in IE8, normal buttons are displayed higher up. Chrome displays exactly how I expect, versions of IE lower than 8 aren't important.

Here is a screenshot showing the problem: http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/1504/layoutissue.jpg

The actual page is fairly complex, and generated with JS, so I can't copy/paste it here. I don't know what other CSS to post to give people an idea either, but if anyones interested I'll PM you my IP so you can have a look.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the invalid HTML, I can duplicate the issue, so that clearly means the invalid HTML isn't the cause :)

This appears to be an issue with inline-block styled elements with overflow set to anything other than visible. Check out this simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
span
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
#b
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<span id="a">test</span>

<span id="b">test2test2test2test2test2test2test2test2test2test2test2test2test2</span>
</body>

</html>
```

The second span shows up just how you describe. However, if you change those spans to display: block, and float them, they will line up vertically.

It looks like this is a bug in the two browsers where it doesn't work as expected. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to fix it the way you are styling it now, but you should be able to redo your styles to use floats to get the same overall look for that box.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I've now overridden the toolbar using display:block and float:inline as suggested, everythings lining up nicely! Noticed a minor issue I should be able to sort, the toolbar div is 4px taller than the tallest span in all browsers, but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with padding or margins.

Comment: Also, wasn't aware of the no block-elements inside inline-element rule, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

overflow:hidden, hides vertical and horizontal overflow, 
its possible that you are stretching box vertically

you need to check margin, padding, line-height and fontsizes used.

Fire-Bug is very helpful in these cases to see what going on, and where is 
extra space coming from as you can toggle css properties on/off.

Hope it helps.
P.S. you can send me IP i will take a quick look...

Comment: I've looked at it with firebug, can't see anything change with and without though. Looks like there isn't a PM system here... If you send me an email to [removed] I'll forward you the IP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the size of the label or some other element is smaller than the total size of elements inside it, and adding `overflow: hidden` prevents it from stretching to accommodate its larger children, but rather stays at the predefined size.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without even sample HTML/CSS that replicates the problem, it's going to be very hard to resolve this, but one thing that could be a problem is that your HTML is invalid here. A `<label>` does not allow block-level elements inside it, which both `<iframe>` and `<p>` are. The various browsers may not have a consistent handling of this situation because they don't need to in order to be compliant with the spec.

Comment: Span is also an inline element, so as such you cannot legally put block elements inside that either. You aren't supposed to put any block element inside any inline element. Not sure if this is the cause of the problem here at all, but it could cause other issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the paragraph the style overflow-x: hidden so it's just the width the overflow affects?

Comment: Sounds like that should work, but it didn't, did the same thing :S

Comment: I've emailed you there if you want to send on the IP? Wouldn't mind seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

bugzilla already knows about this bug, to fix it just set vertical-align: top; to the spans or divs, regards